# For html canvas, how to use clip() with a text as a path?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wrote the following code which is similar to my objective but falls short; because I want to fill inside the text in multiple colors; currently only in #FF00FF.

[Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/vz8bu90a/#&togetherjs=GiV6tPpbew)

I think the problem is that I don't know how to use the text "ABC" as the clipping path. Please show me how to do it, or any answer equivalent for my objective.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>canvas</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('sample');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i=1;i<100;i++){
       //mock1: ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + [i, i, i] + ")";
       ctx.moveTo(0,5*i);
       ctx.lineTo(380,5*i);
       ctx.lineTo(300,5*i+3);
       ctx.lineTo(0,5*i+3);
       ctx.lineTo(0,5*i);
       }
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.clip();

    ctx.font = "bold 72px 'Sans-selif'";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";  
    ctx.fillText("ABC", 90, 60);
    
    
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test()">
<h2>Canvas</h2>
<canvas width="300" height="150" id="sample" style="background-color:yellow;">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to fill inside the text in multiple colors"? Like a gradient? One color per letter? Something else? How would using the text as clipping area help here?

Comment: @Kaiido, thank you very much. Currently some lines pass through "ABC" . I mean giving different colors to these lines to each other.

Comment: Can you create a mock of the expected result?

Comment: @Kaiido, thank you very much. I added a comment titled as mock1 in the code. And paste it here too. //mock1: ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + [i, i, i] + ")";  I think it does not work, but I think it express my intention somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2DCanvas API unfortunately doesn't expose the text's contour in a way it could be used as a Path2D or in methods like `clip()` or `isPointInPath()`.
However for what you wish to do, you don't need a path, this can be done by using [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) instead of clipping:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('sample');
if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // draw the full lines first
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 5 * i);
    ctx.lineTo(380, 5 * i);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 5 * i + 3);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 5 * i + 3);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 5 * i);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
  ctx.fill();

  // with this mode
  // every previous pixel that is not under the next drawing
  // will get cleared
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"

  ctx.font = "bold 72px 'Sans-serif'";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
  ctx.fillText("ABC", 90, 60);

  // reset to default mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"

}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="150" id="sample" style="background-color:yellow;"></canvas>
```